# Difference between constructor and connectedCallback in custom elements v1

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am new to web development and recently I have been seeing much debate and talks about Custom Elements v1. They allow you to define your own elements with their own custom behaviors and if Shadow DOM is used, with scoped styles. 
When I was learning about it in [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) site, I did not understand the table under "Custom element reactions". Can anyone please explain the difference between using the "constructor" and "connectedCallback" and also the terms "created or upgraded" and "inserted into the DOM"?. 

For extra information, my custom element's definition is in a separate file and it uses shadow DOM. I used HTML Import to import the element's definition into the main document.

Comment: constructor gets called if you do something like var button = document.createElement('fancy-button'), whereas connectedCallback would only be called once you do document.body.appendChild(button); That is, it is appended to an element in the dom.

Comment: What if we declare the tag directly in the main document as "<fancy-button></fancy-button>"?

Comment: Seems in that case there is no real difference save that one is called before the other : https://jsfiddle.net/ddjvxkpd/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As already stated by Juvian in the comments:

- `constructor()` is called when the element is *created*.
- `connectedCallback()` is called when (after) the element is attached to the DOM.

The [`constructor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) call is not specific to Custom Elements, it occurs with any object creation (typically created with the `new` operator), and not only HTML Elements.

In the `constructor()` call, you can create the Shadow DOM, but you can't add Nodes inside the normal DOM, and you can't add or set an attribute either.

About *upgrade*:

The *upgrade* occurs when an unknown tag declared in the HTML code is defined afterwards (by the `customElements.define()` method). The "unknown" element becomes a "custom" element. The `constructor()` and `connectedCallback()` methods are then called.

*Note*: when an element is created (as unknown), and then defined, it is upgraded only when attached.

```js
class CE extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.info( 'constructed' )
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.info( 'connected' )
    this.innerHTML = 'Hello'  //can't be set in constructor()
  }
}


B1.onclick = function () {
  ce = document.createElement( 'c-e' )
  ce.textContent = 'unknown'
}

B2.onclick = function () {
  document.body.appendChild( ce )
}

B3.onclick = function () {
  customElements.define( 'c-e', CE)  
}
```

```html
<button id=B1>create</button>
<button id=B2>attach</button>
<button id=B3>define</button>
```

Try different combinations with the above snippet:

- Run then: 1 Create - 2 Attach - 3 Define
- Run then: 1 Create - 2 Define - 3 Attach
- Run then: 1 Define - 2 Create - 3 Attach

Comment: Currently in Chrome, I can set `this.innerHTML` inside the constructor.

Comment: @kzh only if you define the custom element after its rendering (i.e. upgrade of an unknown element). it's not the more frequent use case, and not supported by the spec.

Comment: @Supersharp Is there a simple way to pass values from the HTML to the constructor?
Ie, `<button id=B1>create</button>` and then the constructor has access to the id?
It seems silly to find out id only in connected callback

Comment: @BigGuy maybe you should formulate a question, I don't see what you want exactly

Comment: Now you can also call [CustomElementRegistry.upgrade()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/upgrade) yourself before `ce` is connected: `customElements.upgrade(ce)`